# Where to validate type creation parameters

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I've seen and used all sort of different ways to create objects, but haven't yet found any pattern to follow when validating the data needed to create that same object.

That said, what's the preferred way of doing it?

```
public SomeClass(Product product, Device device, PlatformType platformType, User user, Country country)
{
    if (environment == null || environment.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("environment");
    if (device == null || device.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("device");
    if (country == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("country");
    if (userContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userContext");
    if (platformType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("platformType");

    Product = product;
    Device = device;
    PlatformType = platformType;
    UserContext = userContext;
    Country = country;
}
```

OR

```
public static class SomeClassFactory()
{
    public static SomeClass Create(Product product, Device device, PlatformType platformType, User user, Country country)
    {
        if (environment == null || environment.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("environment");
        if (device == null || device.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("device");
        if (country == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("country");
        if (userContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userContext");
        if (platformType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("platformType");
    }

    return new SomeClass(product, device, platformType, user, country);
}
```

According to the Fail-fast principle both of them seem right approaches, I'm just not sure about the first one, because if you're creating an object it makes sense that you validate all the data you're going to use before you even attempt to create it, and because you want to reuse that validation the factory patterns makes more sense, but maybe it us just a matter of taste.

Comment: According to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) you should not give the responsibility to the class to validate itself (otherwise you class cannot have any other responsibility). Better make another class responsible for the validation (or maybe only a method factory as you mentionned).

Comment: @Spotted thanks for your comment. That's exactly what I thought, but at the same point, lets say your class has only one constructor and you don't have any other types in the same namespace you can' reuse your factory for their creating, would you still create create a factory with a single method? I could as well have the builder pattern for that object and apply the validations in the Build method, but then again, does it make sense to have a build type if the target has one constructor only?

Comment: you are right, neither a factory or a builder should be responsible for that (plus in your context doesn't make sense to implement). I'll post an answer with how I'll do the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not very familiar with this kind of validation.

These are my thoughts on different solutions:

## Factory

Pros

- Regroup the validation in one place in case of many implementations needing the same validation

Cons

- It won't prevent someone to construct the object directly (without modifying the class you provided)
- You have only one implementation, therefore the responsibility of a factory (providing the good implementation according to some arguments) is useless

## Builder

Pros

- Allow you to create objects in a "fluent-style" (is it really a pro ?)

Cons

- This may break the potential immutability of `SomeClass`. Disclaimer: I'm in favor of immutable classes
- Since you only have one constructor without optionnal arguments, the builder seems useless

## Validator

You can delegate the responsibility to a validator containing some rules (in your case only one rule: `ObjectNotNull`).

## Reject the responsibility

It may be the case where the responsibility to provide consistent arguments is left to the caller. If `SomeClass` is only used internally, you could assume that.

## Maybe it's not a responsibility

After all, my first assumption may be false and performing some null checks is not a responsibility in itself but you can see it like "patching some weakness of the caller's code because he's too lazy for not providing non-null values". Therefore, your first solution seems perfectly legit.

Hope my thinking could help you.

Comment: There are ways to "prevent" the object from being created outside of the scope of the factory, not completely though, but you could use partial classes and set the target class to private or use the internal (c#)modifier and make sure that any consumer code is places in a different assembly. Yes as I said, the builder pattern is useless in this case, cause there's only on constructor without any optional parameters. As for your solution, that takes me to the same problem, the object will be calling the validator from within the constructor,so the object will be validating itself upon creation.